# join/merge data frames in R

Tags: r, join

I would like to join similar data frames:

```
input:
x <- data_frame(a=c(1,2,3,4),b=c(4,5,6,7),c=c(1,NA,NA,NA))
y <- data_frame(a=c(2,3),b=c(5,6),c=c(1,2))

desired output:
z <- data_frame(a=c(1,2,3,4),b=c(4,5,6,7),c=c(1,1,2,NA))
```

I tried

```
x <- data_frame(a=c(1,2,3,4),b=c(4,5,6,7),c=c(1,NA,NA,NA))
y <- data_frame(a=c(2,3),b=c(5,6),c=c(1,2))

z <- merge(x,y, all=TRUE)
```

but it has one inconvenience:

```
  a b  c
1 1 4  1
2 2 5  1
3 2 5 NA
4 3 6  2
5 3 6 NA
6 4 7 NA
```

It doubles rows where there are similarities. Is there a way to get desired output without deleting unwanted rows?

**EDIT**

I can not delete rows with `NA`, `x` data frame consists of rows with NA which are not in y data frame. If I would do this I would deleted 4th row from `x` data frame `(4 7 NA)`

Thanks for help

Comment: @Jaap your example gives solution by deleting NA values. I can not do this in my example - rows with NA (no duplicated have to stay)

Comment: I've undeleted my answer. As you can see, it is the exact same approach as in the linked questions imo.

Comment: thanks you are right your answer is exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an update join with the `data.table` package:

```
# load the packge and convert the dataframes to data.table's
library(data.table)
setDT(x)
setDT(y)

# update join
x[y, on = .(a, b), c := i.c][]
```

which gives:

> ```
>    a b  c
> 1: 1 4  1
> 2: 2 5  1
> 3: 3 6  2
> 4: 4 7 NA
> ```